# Unable to edit metadata in corpus

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I have the following corpus:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tm)

query = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ebisearch/ws/rest/pride?query=submitter_country:Norway&size=1000&fields=submitter_keywords&format=json"
datasets.raw <- fromJSON(query, flatten = TRUE, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)

datasets.df <- datasets.raw$entries
datasets.df
keywords.corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(datasets.df$fields.submitter_keywords))
```

I'd like to edit the metadata of this corpus with some custom values. However, running this does not do the trick

```
meta(keywords.corp[[1]], "description") <- "hello"
meta(keywords.corp[[1]], "description")
"character(0)"
```

This is a bit unexpected behavior, as I'm able to do this on some example data:

```
data("crude")
meta(crude[[1]], "description") <- "hello"
meta(crude[[1]], "description)
[1] "hello"
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Use `VCorpus` instead of `Corpus` when you create `keywords.corp` Let me know if that doesn't do everything you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick!